# Can't save the password in connection manager in SSIS package, it's replaced with *** (stars) after publishing

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, ssis-connection-manager

I have a SSIS package shifted to ADF, it's connected to Azure SQL Server, but every time I publish, the password in connection manager is being replaced with ********** star symbols.  [image: password replaced] - obviously its impossible to connect to DB after that and I have to replace password with actual one again to run the pipeline. Have 'Protection Level: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey' in the SSIS project.

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic content and passing pipeline parameter as password?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to replace password with actual one again to run the pipeline.

To resolve this issue you can use `dynamic content` for pipeline.

- In pipeline we can create string **variable** or a **pipeline parameter** and then use that variable or parameter in pipeline while runtime.
  [image]
- Using dynamic expression, you can fetch it like below:
  [image]
- It will take its default value automatically in runtime.so you don't need to put it in for every run.